# Why is an absolute positioned widget not shown?

Tags: python, pyqt5, position, qt5, python-3.8

Using Qt5 I am trying to make a widget work using absolute positioning. The code below is a minimum working example of something I am trying to do. A quick walk through of the code:

- `CentralWidget` is the central widget of the main window and holds `MyWidget` using absolute positioning, e.g. without using any layouts.
- `MyWidget` does not set its child widgets immediately but provides a `SetData` method which first removes all current child widgets and then adds the new child widgets to its layout.
- `SetData` is triggered using a timer in the main window.

I commented out two lines of code. The first "enables" relative positioning using layouts by adding a layout to `CentralWidget`. This line shows what I am trying to achieve but with absolute positioning. The second comment enables some debug information:

```
MyWidget
  layout.count: 3
  size: PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(-1, -1)
  sizeHint: PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(200, 100)

CentralWidget
  size: PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(18, 18)
  sizeHint: PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(18, 18)
```

What I am doing wrong in order for `MyWidget` to be visible using absolute positioning?

Code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    z = 0

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

    def SetData(self):
        while self._layout.count() > 0:
            widget = self._layout.takeAt(0).widget()
            widget.hide()
            widget.deleteLater()

        for i in range(3):
            self._layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(str(MyWidget.z * 10 + i)))

        MyWidget.z += 1


class CentralWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._myWidget = MyWidget(self)

        # QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self).addWidget(self._myWidget)

    def SetData(self):
        self._myWidget.SetData()
        # print("MyWidget\n  layout.count: {}\n  size: {}\n  sizeHint: {}\n\nCentralWidget\n  size: {}\n  sizeHint: {}\n\n".format(self._myWidget.layout().count(), self.sizeHint(), self.size(), self._myWidget.sizeHint(), self._myWidget.size()))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        centralWidget = CentralWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self._timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self._timer.timeout.connect(centralWidget.SetData)
        self._timer.start(500)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: try replacing the line `self._layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)` with `self._layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(parent)`

Comment: @S.Nick Your suggestion does display the labels but it is not what I am after. Your suggestion adds a layout to `CentralWidget` and in consequence does not use absolute positioning for the labels.

Comment: If I recall correctly you should explicitly call `self._myWidget.show()` after creating it if you don't use layouts.

Comment: @titusjan Nope, calling `self._myWidget.show()` does not paint the widget into the window :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is directly related to the fact that the widget is not added to a layout *and* its contents are added after being shown.

In fact, if you call `centralWidget.SetData()` upon initialization and before `mainWindow.show()`, it will work as expected.

A lot of things happen when you add a child widget to a layout, and this usually involves multiple calls to the children size hints, allowing the parent to adapt its own size hint, and, *after that*, adapt its size and that of its children.

If that "container widget" is itself contained in another layout, that widget will be automatically resized (based on its hint) in the next cycle of events, but this doesn't happen in your case, since yours is a "free" widget.

The function you are looking for is [`QWidget.adjustSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#adjustSize), but, for the aforementioned reasons, you cannot call it immediately after adding the children widgets.
To overcome your issue, you can call [`QApplication.processEvents()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) before `adjustSize()`, or, eventually, use a 0-based single shot QTimer:

```
    def SetData(self):
        while self._layout.count() > 0:
            widget = self._layout.takeAt(0).widget()
            widget.hide()
            widget.deleteLater()

        for i in range(3):
            self._layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(str(MyWidget.z * 10 + i)))

        MyWidget.z += 1

        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.adjustSize)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already experimented with `adjustSize` but got strange results because I did't put it in a timer or call `processEvents`. Do you have a reference to a document where *"A lot of things happen when you add a child widget to a layout"* is described in more detail?

Comment: @Woltan unfortunately, no. I only know that from experience and by studying the source code of widgets and layouts.