# How to change images with key press events in PyQt5, python

Tags: python, pyqt5, keypress

I just want to show different images whenever I press keys.
Different keys are connected to different functions which show different image or do different things.

There is text at first, and after press spacebar key, the text is deleted and 'image 1' is appeared. I want to change image which is shown on screen whenever I press the keyboard button 'F' or 'J'
, but nothing is happened after I press space bar key.

Here are my codes below.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class StartExp(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.expUI()
        
    def expUI(self):                           
        self.setWindowTitle("ver.1")
        self.resize(500, 500)

        self.information()

    def information(self):
        # information
        self.info1 = QLabel(f"Hi, there!", self)
        self.info1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.info1)

        self.setLayout(layout)


    def image1(self):

        fix_h = 100
        fix_w = 100

        self.img1 = QLabel(self)
        image1 = QPixmap('1.jpg')
        self.img1.setPixmap(image1)
        self.img1.move(fix_w, fix_h)

    def image2(self):

        fix_h = 100
        fix_w = 100

        self.img2 = QLabel(self)
        image2 = QPixmap('2.jpg')
        self.img2.setPixmap(image2)
        self.img2.move(fix_w, fix_h)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()
        elif e.key() ==Qt.Key_F:

            self.clearimage2()
            self.image1()
            self.update()
            
        elif e.key() ==Qt.Key_J:
            self.clearimage1()
            self.image2()
            self.update()

        elif e.key() == Qt.Key_Space:
            self.clearinfo()
            self.image1()
            self.update()

    def clearinfo(self):
        try:
            self.info1.clear()
        except:
            pass
    def clearimage1(self):
        try:
            self.info1.clear()
        except:
            pass
    def clearimage2(self):
        try:
            self.image2.clear()
        except:
            pass



def run():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainExp = StartExp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Comment: This looks like a typo: `def clear.image1(self):` shouldn't it be `def clearimage1(self):`?

Comment: @tromgy thanks! I found it! I just removed a lot of other things of my codes to show important part of the problem, so I retyped the codes. But, even though I changed the typo, still, after spacebar nothing is shown..

Comment: @bbang please merge the code into a single block, so that we could properly read and test it.

Comment: @bbang please provide a [mre]. Also read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is an absolute positioned widget not shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517365/why-is-an-absolute-positioned-widget-not-shown)

Comment: You should add `self.img1.show()` and `self.img2.show()` after creating the labels. On the other hand, you should *not* continuously create new labels everytime the function is called, but possibly create them at the beginning (in the `__init__`) and eventually show/hide them when necessary. Finally, you should use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) instead of fixed geometries.